# Is a horizontal line considered periodic?

Tags: periodic-functions

Given the following definition of a periodic function:

$$\exists P, P > 0, f(x + P) = f(x)$$

It is possible to argue that $f(x)=k$ ($k$ being a constant) is a periodic function, since you can define $P$ to be any given constant within the real numbers and the definition would be valid. ($f(x + P) = f(x)$ will always be true if $P\in \mathbb R$).

So my question is, can a horizontal line be considered periodic, even when its period is ambiguous?

Comment: Periods are ambiguous in other cases. For example, $\sin \theta$ has periods $2\pi k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Of course, you could pick a minimal period in that case. But, I don't see the problem. I mean, the constant function is part of the family of periodic functions built over any period. This is a good thing.

Comment: Based on the definition of periodic, it looks that way!

Comment: Yes I would say so under this definition. If you want something less trivial, it might behoove one to ask that there exists a *smallest* $P>0$ such that $f(x+P)=f(x)$ for all $x$.